# How do salts affect pH?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, biochemistry, salt, physical-organic-chemistry

Since pH measures the effective proton concentration, it is the concentration of a very specific type of cation. I know if salt reacts with water, it will affect pH. But my question is, how does the presence of salt affect the pH in general in aqueous solvents, especially for, say, a protein where there are many titratable protons? Can pH and ion concentrations be considered to be totally decoupled from one another in such cases?

Comment: See [ionic strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_strength),  [activity coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_coefficient), [Debye-Hückel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye%E2%80%93H%C3%BCckel_equation) and [pH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH)